# Broadcom QLogic 57800 shows up as two adapters in ESXi 6

Tags: vmware-esxi, broadcom, qlogic

I don't have another quad card as a reference, but the Broadcom QLogic 57800 is a 2 x 10GbE + 2 x 1GbE quad card, which has sequential MACs and same PCI slot, but shows up as two dual adapters in ESXi 6.

Is this normal?  I'm seeing [other oddities](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42085/incorrect-mac-address-in-switch-mac-table) and am wondering if there's a VIB/driver issue.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a need to change the firmware of the NICS take a look here - http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=THCKX

Comment: Are you certain that this isn't by design, quad NIC showing as 2 interfaces?